# In an eclipse based IDE, how do you access remote files through two ssh connections?

Tags: eclipse, ssh, zend-studio

I'm working remotely and I need to access files on a server that's only accessible through ssh from another machine.

For example if my files are on server2, I need to ssh me@server1 then once I'm on that machine, ssh me@server2

Is there a way to set up remote systems in eclipse (I'm using Zend Studio) to get access to my files?

Thanks.

Comment: I should also mention that I don't have access to forward ports or install software or modify the system

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is No, however you you do have some options...

Eclipse is only aware of files in an Eclipse workspace (with some exceptions), thus you need to make your files available to your Eclipse instance. To do so, you could download the remote files and make them available locally or make te files accessible via a network share.

All in all, you need to make those files available on a file system visible to the local Eclipse instance. Once that is done, you can add/import the file into your Eclipse workspace.